# How to use raw YAML file inside a curl to create Pod

Tags: curl, kubernetes, yaml

I am trying to create a Pod in Kubernetes using `curl`.

This is the YAML:

```
cat > nginx-pod.yaml <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.7.9
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
EOF
```

I have token with permissions to do it and I wrote the following `curl` command:

```
curl -k -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods --data '{"name":"","namespace":"default","content":"apiVersion: v1\nkind: Pod\nmetadata:\n  name: nginx1\nspec:\n  containers:\n  - name: nginx\n    image: nginx:1.7.9\n    ports:\n    - containerPort: 80\n","validate":true}'
```

Which should be equivalent to the `nginx-pod.yaml` file.
The YAML is ok because when I run`kubectl create -f nginx.pod.yaml` it creates it.
But when I tried to run it with `curl` I received:

```
< Content-Length: 617
<
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Pod \"\" is invalid: [metadata.name: Required value: name or generateName is required, spec.containers: Required value]",
  "reason": "Invalid",
  "details": {
    "kind": "Pod",
    "causes": [
      {
        "reason": "FieldValueRequired",
        "message": "Required value: name or generateName is required",
        "field": "metadata.name"
      },
      {
        "reason": "FieldValueRequired",
        "message": "Required value",
        "field": "spec.containers"
      }
    ]
  },
  "code": 422
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

I tried to change the `Content-Type` to `Content-type: text/x-yaml` but it didn't help.

Any idea what can be the reason?

One of the errors is regarding the "metadata.name" field.

Comment: I bet that `kubectl` reads the YAML and then emits JSON when talking to the  API. You would need to take care of that conversion yourself, or just create JSON files in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you set content type to application/yaml, and use --binary-data with yaml… --data drops newlines

Comment: I tried like you wrote: `curl -k -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H 'Content-type: application/yaml' https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods --data-binary '{"name":"","namespace":"default","content":"apiVersion: v1\nkind: Pod\nmetadata:\n  name: nginx2\nspec:\n  containers:\n  - name: nginx\n    image: nginx:1.7.9\n    ports:\n    - containerPort: 80\n","validate":true}'"` but received the same error.

Comment: I tried to do like appear here: https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/advisories/minikube-rce/
he ran something similar: `$ curl 'http://192.168.99.100:30000/api/v1/appdeploymentfromfile'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8'  --data '{"name":"","namespace":"default","content":"apiVersion: v1\nkind: Pod\nmetadata:\n  ... \n","validate":true}'`

Comment: --binary-data with yaml file works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The payloads don't seem equivalent.

This is the JSON payload you are sending:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "namespace": "default",
  "content": "apiVersion: v1\nkind: Pod\nmetadata:\n  name: nginx1\nspec:\n  containers:\n  - name: nginx\n    image: nginx:1.7.9\n    ports:\n    - containerPort: 80\n",
  "validate": true
}
```

Your payload should be something like this. I created this with `kubectl convert -f <yaml.file> -o=json`, which is what I believe `kubectl` does before sending the payload.

```
{
    "kind": "Pod",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "nginx1",
        "creationTimestamp": null
    },
    "spec": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "name": "nginx",
                "image": "nginx:1.7.9",
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "containerPort": 80,
                        "protocol": "TCP"
                    }
                ],
                "resources": {},
                "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
                "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
            }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "securityContext": {},
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
    },
    "status": {}
}
```

Tried this and it works fine for me:

```
curl -k -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods -d@payload.json
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to be able to send raw YAML file inline. Saving it as JSON file is a nice workaround but I wanted to make it in one line for some demo I am doing.

Comment: BTW, after `convert` you should add `-f` before the YAML file.

Comment: Thanks, changed the answer. For a oneliner, you can just remove the newlines on the JSON payload

Answer (score 0):

Each line of a yaml file contains line breaks (`\n`). Curl removes line breaks when use with the `-d` option which change the actual yaml format. To avoid this, use `--data-binary` option instead of `-d` option when using yaml files as data. Further its better to use Content-Type as application/x-yaml.